# Form.Show() Crashing When Called

Tags: c#

I've have made my program do what I want it to do, which is to make the screen flash white and slowly fade out. When I compile and run it in Visual Studio 2013, it works flawlessly, but when I run it from the bin folder where the .exe is located, the screen just stays white and doesn't do anything then crashes.

Here is my code:

```
public static void StartForm() {

  Form Form1 = new Form();
  Form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  Form1.Size = new Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
  Form1.BackColor = Color.White;
  Form1.Show();

  for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
    Form1.Update();
    Form1.Opacity = Form1.Opacity - .01;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
  }
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
  Form1.Hide();
}
```

Comment: No message pump, no cookie.

Comment: Put try catch in your application and check what is the exception message

Comment: What's the output message while debugging? Any kind of exceptions?

Comment: It should always crash, Opacity becomes less than 0.  Windows 7 is buggy, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Application.DoEvents in your for loop to allow messages to be processed.